# Change all NaT values in Pandas dataframe to Timedelta 00:00:00

Tags: python, pandas, nat

I have a dataframe in Pandas, and one column "timeOff" has some NaT values.

All I want to do is change all the NaT values to timeDelta values with '00:00:00' as the value.

This is my current output:

[Output with NaT values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pc1x.png)

I have tried to run this line of code:

```
replaceNaT = pd.to_timedelta('00:00:00')
print(replaceNaT)

startEndEventsDataframe['timeOff'] = np.where(pd.isnull(startEndEventsDataframe['timeOff']) == True, replaceNaT, startEndEventsDataframe['timeOff'])
```

But this destroys all the values in my dataframe column, as seen below:

[After running code from above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pHuO.png)

I would like for all the values that are not NaT to remain unchanged, and I would like all values that are NaT to be timeDelta with values "00:00:00".

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you try `startEndEventsDataframe['timeOff'] = startEndEventsDataframe['timeOff'].fillna(pd.to_timedelta('00:00:00'))`?

Comment: This actually works as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

So, as it turns out I figured it out on my own, but figured I would post the solution to anybody who might need to know in the future.

I got rid of the "replaceNaT" and simply wrote "0" in where NaT was found.  I guess timeDeltas are stored as integers based on the lowest resolution of time they measure, and are only converted to look like they do when they are displayed?

Anyways, here is the code change that worked for me:

```
startEndEventsDataframe['timeOff'] = np.where(pd.isnull(startEndEventsDataframe['timeOff']) == True, 0, startEndEventsDataframe['timeOff'])
```